# All files from Ubuntu One are gone after re-installing windows 7

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows-7, files

I ran Natty for a while, then switched to Maverick. Once I was on Maverick, I set up Ubuntu One and synced all of my school files. No problem so far.

Then I had to wipe my HD and install Windows, since I had a critical project due that I couldn't figure out how to do in Ubuntu (I would have run a VM, but I couldn't get it to work for some reason).

Now I log into Ubuntu One from my Windows 7 machine, and all of my files are gone!! These are my school files, guys, including a term paper that's due in not long at all.

Please please PLEASE tell me they're not gone forever!!

Comment: Let me understand better: The problem is that the document in your Ubuntu One Box are gone? Or are you talking about file that were in a partition in your hard drive and got formatted?

Comment: This should probably go through proper Ubuntu One support so the right people can help you: https://one.ubuntu.com/support/contact/

Answer (score 1):

I think your Ubuntu One files are still there but didn't sync on Windows 7 because the Ubuntu one client for windows still isn't stable and It never worked for me either (Never synced on Windows 7 for me).

If this is the case then you should be able to access all your Ubuntu One files from the web interface on https://one.ubuntu.com Go to the link and sign in and you'd be able to access your synced files.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu one helps in synchronizing your files with a remote server. You should be able to get your files when you log into your Ubuntu one on the web and download whatever you synced with it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete the UbuntuOne folder first while it was in sync and then removed Ubuntu and put Windows? If you deleted the files first then they are gone.

If you just removed Ubuntu can you describe the process you used to do that?

Also for running windows programs, use Wine or Crossover Linux rather than installing Windows every time you need it.